# How to check an item is present in the Model

Tags: c#, html, razor, model-view-controller

My controller code looks like below

```
    [HttpPost]
    public string Rating(int id, int rate, double avgrating)
    {
        rating rating = new rating();
        rating.date = DateTime.Now;
        rating.trendid = id;
        rating.rating1 = rate;
        rating.ratedby = User.Identity.Name;

        db.ratings.Add(rating);
        db.SaveChanges();

        return "{\"error\":false}";
    }
```

In the view I have written a code as below

```
         @using (Html.BeginForm("Rating", "Article"))
            {
                <h4>Please Rate the Article</h4>
                <table id="temp" class: "table" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="7.5" style="text-align:center">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr class="rowc">
                            <td class="col1 cel1">Please Obselete</td>
                            <td class="col2 cel1">Not Very Useful</td>
                            <td class="col3 cel1">Helpful</td>
                            <td class="col4 cel1">Useful</td>
                            <td class="col5 cel1">Excellent</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr class="rowb">
                            <td class="col1 cel1">
                                @Html.RadioButton("rate","1") 
                            </td>
                            <td class="col2 cel1">
                                @Html.RadioButton("rate","2")
                            </td>
                            <td class="col3 cel1">
                                @Html.RadioButton("rate","3")
                            </td>
                            <td class="col4 cel1">
                                @Html.RadioButton("rate","4")
                            </td>
                            <td class="col5 cel1">
                                @Html.RadioButton("rate","5")
                            </td>
                        </tr>

                    </tbody>
                </table>
                @Html.HiddenFor(m => Model.id);
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Rate!</button>
            }
```

Now the part I don't understand is I have a rating saved as below in the code

```
        @{
            double rating = 0;
            double count = 0;

            if (Model.ratings.Select(r => r.rating1).Count() > 0)
            {
                rating = Model.ratings.Select(r => r.rating1).Average();
                count = Model.ratings.Select(r => r.rating1).Count();
            }

        }
```

my rating.cs looks like below

```
namespace SVMD.Models
{
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public partial class rating
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime date { get; set; }
    public int trendid { get; set; }
    public int rating1 { get; set; }
    public string ratedby { get; set; }

    public virtual trend trend { get; set; }
}
}
```

The questions I have is

1. How do I pass rating populated as Model.ratings.Select(r =>
   r.rating1).Count(); to the controller to populate avgrating?
2. I want to show the rating tab only if the current user is not
   present in ratedby list. I'm not sure how to accomplish that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pass entire object from view to controller in ASP.NET MVC 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39212899/pass-entire-object-from-view-to-controller-in-asp-net-mvc-5)

Comment: Thanks that helped me answer #1.  But it would be great if I can get some help on #2.

Comment: Could you describe what is the *rating tab*? Do you mean the form from the second code snippet?

Comment: yes that's correct. I only want to second code snippet if that corresponding user has not rated before. Basically trying to block a person doing multiple rating.

Comment: You could use [Logic Conditions](https://www.w3schools.com/asp/razor_cs_logic.asp) to solve that snippet will be executed. But you need to know current user identificator in this case.

Comment: Forgive my ignorance here. I know about Logic Conditions but what I'm not able to understand how will I lookup in the list. Basically what I want is something like I want to whether UserName is present in Model.ratings.ratedby list. But not able to understand the syntax for the same.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145714/discussion-between-user3917144-and-alexander).