# MVC Open a new tab from tablebutton with data of row

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I need to open a view in a new tab in an MVC application from a table button.

I want to pass the data row from table to the new page.

This is the table:

```
@if (Model.Rows != null)
{
    foreach (var row in Model.Rows)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@Html.ActionLink(" ", "Download", "Controller", new { @class = "glyphicon glyphicon-pencil", @title = "Modify" })</td>
            <td>@row.Progressivo</td>
            <td>@row.Committente</td>
            <td style="display:none;">@row.CommittenteId</td>
            <td style="display:none;">@row.CorriereId</td>
        </tr>
    }
}
```

What is the best mode to implement this solution in MVC?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the [target](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_target.asp) attribute to `_blank`, this will cause the link to be opened in a new browser tab.

Pass the ID of the current row as parameter to the `Download` action, it can load the row data again from DB. Or pass all required data as parameters.

```
@Html.ActionLink(" ", "Download", "Controller", 
    new { @class = "glyphicon glyphicon-pencil", 
          @title = "Modify", 
          target ="_blank", 
          id = row.Id 
    }
)
```

See also [How to have a a razor action link open in a new tab?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10851860/how-to-have-a-a-razor-action-link-open-in-a-new-tab)

Comment: Thank you. is it possible to pass the entire row of Model.Rows as parameter to the controller?

Comment: Yes, it is theoretically possible, but not recommended for GET requests (because the model can have so many properties that you run into limitations of the query string length). See https://stackoverflow.com/a/11600966/1450855, https://stackoverflow.com/a/39212972/1450855